# Linux VM stuck in Provisioning for last 2hrs

Tags: azure, centos, virtual-machine

I had a CENTOS VM running fine, it was hosting a website.

I captured the image using these instructions, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/
The image I created is visible even on the azure management portal.

I have tried to create a new VM using the Image but the new VM is stuck in provisioning for last 2 hrs.

I have tried again to create a new VM using the Image and a Reserved IP, that is also stuck for last 2 hrs.

Another question is : How can I re-provision my original VM? I can't see it any more using the azure management portal and also using azure CLI tools.

I have asked this question in the MSDN forums too but so far no response

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Not quite sure what the issue is, but first... post to ServerFault. This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure this is the same question as in ServerFault but I posted here too just in case someone looking ^_^

> I have tried the guide and it works for me (I created new Centos VM
>   and capture it). I tried login to the new VM from the image and I
>   still have my sudo access. So, the guide is correct maybe you just do
>   something wrong in the process. And also make sure you use the new
>   user that you created for the new VM not the old one from the VM that
>   you deprovision.
>
> For the second question, if you deprovision VM and capture it, the VM
>   will be removed so you cannot access it again